# Hide part of phone number

Tags: php, string

I am trying to hide part of phone number of my users to prevent it from phone call spam.

My code displays full user phone number like: 510 200 300 and what i want to achive is to hide most letters with "x" like so: 51X XXX XXX.
Later on i plan to let real user to click on it to show full number.

My code is:

```
function maskPhoneNumber($number){

$number = the_author_meta( 'phone_number', $author_id ); // get user phone number from database
$mask_number =  str_repeat("*", strlen($number)-4) . substr($number, -4);
return $mask_number;

}
echo maskPhoneNumber($number);
```

However it returns nothing. I tried many configurations, but nothing works, please help.

Comment: the function is nearly working. but... the variable `$author_id` is unknown in your function. And what's about the `$number` you pass to the function?

Comment: Why not something like `substr($number, 2) . "X XXX XXXX"`

Comment: Why is this question tagged with JavaScript? Do you want a JavaScript answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
function maskPhoneNumber($number,$digitsToHide){
    $number = the_author_meta( 'phone_number', $author_id ); // get user phone number from database
    $len = strlen($number);
    for($i = ($len-$digitsToHide)-1; $i<$len; $i++){
        $number[$i] = "*";
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: and still `$author_id` will be undefined and so there should be no result

Comment: The question is how to hide part of a phone number. He didn't share the rest of the code so it's unkown whether `$author_id` is a global variable or a function scope one.

Comment: My script knows the value of $author_id, becouse it returns correct phone number for each user. So $author_id is known. The problem is i can't make script to show only part of this number.

Comment: And i tagged this post with javascript because i thought it's the best way to show and hide rest of the hidden phone number with a click.

Comment: @bajcepsme have you tried my code?

Comment: @garry man, yes i tried, but still nothing shows :(

Comment: @bajcepsme try debugging the phone number value before `maskPhoneNumber` function call and after, see what changes.

Comment: Still nothing. It seems like function can't read $author_id indeed. Even though i used global varialbe.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php